# Can't upload and see image from django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to upload images at my model and later on show it at template.

Forms.py:

```
class ClanakForma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clanak
        fields = '__all__'
```

Models.py:

```
class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)   
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor) + ', ' + str(self.videofile)
```

views.py

```
def dodajClanak(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        forma = ClanakForma()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        forma = ClanakForma(request.POST)
        if forma.is_valid():
            data = Clanak()
            data.naslov = forma.cleaned_data['naslov']
            data.datumObjave = forma.cleaned_data['datumObjave']
            data.autor = forma.cleaned_data['autor']
            data.videofile = forma.cleaned_data['videofile']
            #data.email = forma.cleaned_data['email']
            data.save()
            return redirect('readAllNew')
    return render(request, 'justadded.html', {'forma':forma})

def readAllNew(request):
    data = list(Clanak.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'readAllNew.html', {'data':data})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dodajClanak/',views.dodajClanak, name='dodajClanak'),
    path('readAllNew/',views.readAllNew, name='readAllNew'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

justadded.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'dodajClanak' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table border="1">
        {{forma.as_table}}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

readAllNew.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Slika</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.naslov}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datumObjave}}</td>
        <td>{{x.autor}}</td>
        <td><img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ imagefile }}'></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete' x.id %}">delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'edit' x.id %}">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dodajClanak/ and try to upload image I got error:

[image]

On english it says: "You didn't pick any image".

When I go on the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/readAllNew/ I can't see any image:

[image: Image2]

I can upload it through admin site but still can't see it.

[image: Image3]

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: check in your browser the source of the page and look at what's in the <img src="">. That will probably make it easy to figure out your mistake.

Comment: Yeah, seems like good idea, I’ll try that and than I’ll post back informations that I found out

Comment: `MEDIA_URL` isn't defined by default in the template rendering context. You need to add it: `{% load static %}{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_URL %}`

Comment: @dirkgroten First of all I tracked source and my image url is empty (I have it in database and in media folder) so I am surely sending something wrong. It looks like: "<td><img src=''></td>". I added "{% load static %}{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_URL %}" but it won't show nothing as it is empty.

Comment: @dirkgroten I done it with "<td><img src='/media/{{x.videofile}}' height="42" width="42"></td>", thank You on Your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the form to

```
<form action="{% url 'dodajClanak' %}" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
```

and view from this

```
 forma = ClanakForma(request.POST)
    if forma.is_valid():
        data = Clanak()
        data.naslov = forma.cleaned_data['naslov']
        data.datumObjave = forma.cleaned_data['datumObjave']
        data.autor = forma.cleaned_data['autor']
        data.videofile = forma.cleaned_data['videofile']
        #data.email = forma.cleaned_data['email']
        data.save()
        return redirect('readAllNew')
```

to

```
 forma = ClanakForma(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if forma.is_valid():

        forma.save()
        return redirect('readAllNew')
```

as you are using `ModelForm` there is no need to write all those lines

Comment: Thank You, upload works now, but still can't see images on my "readAllNew.html". Am I reading it and displaying it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**Extending @Exprator answer**

try this to display image

```
    <td><img src='{{media_url}}{{ i.videofile.url }}'></td>
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tried, now that field in table is just blank, if needed I can post picture on my original post?

Comment: try to append domain before image

Comment: I am not sure what does that mean?

Comment: Still same, maybe I added wrong settings - "MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')" and "MEDIA_URL= "/media/""? Might it be because image is too large?

Comment: In the end I done it with "<td><img src='/media/{{x.videofile}}' height="42" width="42"></td>", thank You on Your help